# Install a custom package in a docker container that keeps exiting

Tags: java, docker

I have a docker container which runs a springboot java application. Dockerfile:

```
# Create container with java preinstalled
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

# Create app directory
VOLUME /tmp

# Handle Arguments
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG ENV_NAME
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${ENV_NAME}
RUN echo ${ENV_NAME}

# Bundle app source
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY application.yml application.yml

# Run the server
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.config.location=application.yml","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Now, I have a custom library I need to install in that container. I'll need to copy the installation, extract it, run the install script and answer prompts (Y/n)

I understood the easiest way to do this is to connect to the container, install the package and commit the changes.

First - I start the container using:

```
docker run --name local-jdk8 -d openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
```

The next step is to copy the data and run the install script, but the container keeps on exiting since the run command is empty ("/bin/sh") which means I can't run

```
docker exec -it local-jdk8 bash
```

Any ideas on how I can modify such a container?

Comment: Install the library in the Dockerfile you quote in the question.  You can’t modify the base image (and don’t want to because nobody else will have your local changes).

Comment: The problem is that the installation has some prompts (scroll through legal notice, write Yes/No) so how do I get past this using only the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using expect library

My dockerfile :

```
# Create container with java preinstalled
FROM openjdk:8

# Create app directory
VOLUME /tmp

# Handle Arguments
ARG JAR_FILE
ARG ENV_NAME
ARG DRIVER_FILE

# Environment
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${ENV_NAME}
RUN echo ${ENV_NAME}

# Fingerprint Driver
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y expect
COPY ${DRIVER_FILE} driver.tar.gz
COPY driver-install.exp driver-install.exp
RUN tar -xzf driver.tar.gz
RUN /driver-install.exp

# Copy app source
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY application.yml application.yml

# Run the server
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-Dspring.config.location=application.yml","-jar","app.jar"]
```

driver-install.exp is the expect scripts that automatically interacts with the package installation

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is a little trick that allows you to keep your container running to modify and commit it:

```
docker run --name local-jdk8 -d openjdk:8-jdk-alpine tail -f /dev/null
```

Furthermore, there is no `bash` installed on the container so `sh` will have to do:

```
docker exec -it local-jdk8 sh
```

Nevertheless, modifying `Dockerfile` is the better approach, since your change is persisted in code, rather than done on an potentially ephemeral container.